# Jquery FullCalendar not displaying events downloaded from the Web service

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

When the page loads, I initialize the calendar and try to point **eventSources** "**web service**"
Web service is executed, I get the event, but in the calendar are not displayed. 
What am I doing wrong?

*Web service*

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public List<StructEvent> GetEvent()
{
    List<StructEvent> listEvent = DataEvent.GetListEvent();

return listEvent;
}
```

*Initialization calendar*

```
function CreatCalendar() {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            firstDay: 1,
            height: 300,
            axisFormat: 'H(:mm)',
            timeFormat: 'H(:mm)',
            slotDuration: "00:15:00",
            minTime: "08:00:00",
            maxTime: "17:00:00",
            allDaySlot: false,
            allDayDefault: false,
            header: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month,agendaDay'
            },
            eventSources: [LoadEvent()] 
        });      
    });
}

//Loading events from the database
function LoadEvent() {
    $.ajax(
            {
                type: 'POST',
                contentType: 'application/json',
                data: "{}",
                dataType: 'json',
                url: "WebServiceAppointment.asmx/GetEvent",
                cache: false,
                success: function (response) {
                    events: $.map(response.d, function (item, i) {
                        var event = new Object();
                        event.start = new Date(Number(item.StartDate.replace(/[^0-9]/g,'')));
                        event.end = new Date(Number(item.EndDate.replace(/[^0-9]/g,'')));
                        event.title = item.Title;
                        event.color = 'red';
                        event.textColor = 'black';
                        return event;
                    })
                }
            })
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem and I want to share with you the solution. The problem was that:

- When the initialization of the calendar events should be added so
  **eventSources: [{events: LoadEvents()}]**
- Calendar loaded faster than carried Ajax request, and I disabled
  the asynchronous **async:    false**
- Little changed loading event

**working code!**

```
function CreatCalendar() {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            firstDay: 1,
            height: 300,
            axisFormat: 'H(:mm)',
            timeFormat: 'H(:mm)',
            slotDuration: "00:15:00",
            minTime: "08:00:00",
            maxTime: "17:00:00",
            allDaySlot: false,
            allDayDefault: false,
            header: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month,agendaDay'
            },
            eventSources: [{events: LoadEvents()}] 
        });      
    });
}

//Loading events from the database
function LoadEvents() {
    var events = [];
    $.ajax(
            {
                type: 'POST',
                async: false,
                cache: false,
                contentType: 'application/json',
                data: "{}",
                dataType: 'json',
                url: "WebServiceAppointment.asmx/GetEvent",
                cache: false,
                success: function (response) {
                $.map(response.d, function (item, i) {
                    events.push({
                        start: new Date(Number(item.StartDate.replace(/[^0-9]/g,''))),
                        end: new Date(Number(item.EndDate.replace(/[^0-9]/g,''))),
                        title: item.Title,
                        color: "red",
                        textColor: "black"
                    });
                })
            }
            })
    return events;
}
```